# javascript: асинхронный sleep/delay без вложенного setTimeout

Tags: javascript, settimeout, sleep

что-то перерыл пол интернета и не могу найти удовлетворяющее решение:

у меня есть задача:

```
while (data) {
    data = action();
    delay(1000); // синхронная секундная задержка
}
```

как бы сделать корректную функцию `delay`?

причем так, чтобы работала даже в редакторе JS на данном сайте - использование `Promise` вызывает ошибку, что надо в корне документа запускать

делать через `while` и постоянное зачитывание времени тоже вроде как не очень хороший способ - поскольку программа постоянно грузит процессор ненужными вызовами

подскажите, как лучше решить проблему

Comment: "без вложенного setTimeout" --- так это....можно и не вкладывать.....просто его написать **вместо**  while  %)

Comment: @Алексей Шиманский, не совсем понял, а как код выглядеть должен тогда? ведь он отработает 1 раз и мне внутри надо будет запускать его еще один раз - я правильно понимаю? т.е. нужна функция отдельно которая вызывает setTimeout и внутри функции ее вызывать?

Comment: да... setInterval   надо конечно же

Comment: @Алексей Шиманский, тогда при завершении цикла setInterval надо прибить? а если вместо while заданный for на N элементов массива  `for (obj of data) {action(obj); delay(1000};`?

Comment: при завершении не **цикла**, а **данных** - да, интервал прибить

Comment: а ещё есть web worker.... может быть он нужен?

Comment: _использование Promise вызывает ошибку, что надо в корне документа запускать_ - Promise не может вызывать такую ошибку.

Comment: @Grundy, да, виноват, разобрался - это я в `async` функцию код не завернул с `await`

Answer (score 0):

немного разобрался в вопросе - большей части запутался ранее :)

получился такой код, который более-менее устраивает

```
async function process() {

  for (i = 0; i < 10; i ++) {
    console.log(i);
    await new Promise((resolve, reject) => setTimeout(resolve, 3000));
  }
}

process();
console.log('test');
```

Comment: в данном случае `test` будет выведен НЕ после окончания цикла

Comment: да, я понимаю, но все этапы цикла будут реализованы с задержкой как и нужно